# using the count funtion in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a formula I know works in excel:

`=IF(COUNTIF(P11:R11,"=Red")>0,"Red",IF(COUNTIF(P11:R11,"=Amber")>0,"Amber","Green"))`

I need to use this somehow in VBA within a large script I am writing to manipulate a lot of data.  I have three columns and in each column is the traffic light's colors ('Green, Amber, Red'). I need to count how many greens, ambers and red etc, but within each row if I have for example green, amber, green then the cover all would be amber and this is what I am counting. I need to count the overall status of the three.

The data would look something like this: -

```
Green       Green   Green
Green       Amber   Green
Amber       Red     Red
Red         Green   Green
```

This would be Green = 1, amber = 1, red = 2

I then need to input these values in to another Worksheet within the same Workbook. Hope all that made sense and I explained the problem properly.

Comment: I don't understand what you need to count...

Comment: problem is clear, what is not shown or clear is the **coding efforts** you have made to solve this. please show your attempts and where it's failing, otherwise, your question will most likely be closed, or at least downvoted and ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could issue an SQL statement on the cells using an ADO Recordset. The SQL statement would group by a formula that returns the appropriate color per row, and also would also return the count per grouping. Finally, you can use CopyFromRecordset to paste the results into a new worksheet.

Alternatively, you could read the cells into an array, and process the contents of the array line by line. Declare three Integer variables, one for each color, and increment the value of the appropriate variable based on the right value of the line. Then you could write the values of these variables into a new or existing worksheet.